# R Export dataframe to Excel with text columns

Tags: r

I've got a dataframe in R that has around 34000 rows and 10 columns. Some of these columns contain strings. When I try to export to Excel or csv (either via `write.xlsx` or `write.csv` or `write.table`) and then open the file, the results file does not open properly. The format looks very messy and unreadable.

Has anyone got any tips for exporting an R dataframe to Excel or csv, and opening it without any formatting errors in the Excel view?

Comment: Might be worthwhile trying out the `readr` equivalents. For example `write_excel_csv()` seems to be applicable in your situation.

Comment: Thanks. I tried to use it, but the format on opening the file is still not right.

Comment: The first 900 rows look fine, then the format gets messy

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with *openxlsx* library

```
library(openxlsx)
XLSX <- createWorkbook()
addWorksheet(XLSX, "Page name")
writeData(XLSX, "Page name", your_dataframe, startRow = 1, startCol = 1)
saveWorkbook(XLSX, file = "path/data.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
```